# How to use wamp with JSR 356?

Tags: websocket, java-ee-7

[JSR 356](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html) supports subprotocols and I found an exemple of use in [javaee7-samples](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket/subprotocol).

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/endpoint", 
        subprotocols="mySubprotocol")
public class MyEndpoint {
    @OnMessage
    public String echoText(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;
    }
}
```

But I can not find documentation on supported subprotocols. Is there any implementation of wamp ([wamp.ws/spec](http://wamp.ws/spec/)) for the JSR 356 ? And how to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one implementation of wamp in Java (jWamp). You will find more details about it here: http://wamp.ws/implementations/ and here: https://github.com/ghetolay/jwamp.

The problem is, that this implementation is not stable yet and it's only compatible with Jetty.

You can also try to implement it by Your own.

Comment: Yes, I had already find it. But this implementation isn't based on JSR 356.

Comment: Why do You thing so? Jwamp do not include WebSocket implementation but it requires WebSocket implementation to operate. Look at pom.xml, readme.md, and http://wamp.ws/.

Comment: Because this project is based on Jetty 9.0.0.RC2 and Jetty only supports the JSR 356 since this the version 9.1.

Comment: Have You tried to update dependencies in jWamp? From Jetty 9.0.0.RC0 the Jetty WebSocket API has been reworked to better support JSR-356. Therefore it is quite possible that jWamp will work out of the box (after dependency update).

Comment: There's a pending pull request for Jetty 9.1.0 - https://github.com/ghetolay/jwamp/pull/17

Comment: Hopefully They will update libraries sooner than later (last change in repo was made 3 months ago). But You can always do it by Your own, maybe it will work as expected. Regards.

Comment: @pWoz FYI - I am about 99% complete with a major overhaul of jWAMP - and it's JSR356 compliant.  See the MessagingOverhaul branch, the /jwamp-core/src/test/java/com/github/ghetolay/jwamp/rpc/IntegratedRPCTest.java gives you a quick feel for how to get started (there's a similar test for pub/sub).  It is fully functional, just working through some API details.